# Check weather the Users signed up via Facebook in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used omniauth-facebook gem. Want to find weather the user is signed in with facebook provider or not.

My code

```
def sign_in_user_and_redirect(user, identity_id)
   UserIdentity.increment_counter(:sign_in_count, identity_id)
   user.link_browser_id cookies.signed[:uuid]
   sign_in_and_redirect user
   session['devise.user_attributes'] = user.attributes
end
```

How do I find session of user is signed in with facebook or is a normal user.

Comment: did you tried with if current_user.provider == 'facebook'

Comment: yes i tried but want to handle it with session in controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
`def sign_in_user_and_redirect(user, identity_id)
   UserIdentity.increment_counter(:sign_in_count, identity_id)
   user.link_browser_id cookies.signed[:uuid]
   sign_in_and_redirect user
   session[:logged_in_using_omniauth] = true
end`
```

Added helper user_helper.rb

```
`def logged_in_using_omniauth?
  session[:logged_in_using_omniauth].present?
 end`
```

Usage

```
`unless logged_in_using_omniauth?`
```